# Excel VLOOKUP using results from a formula as the lookup value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a cell that I must remove the first 2 characters "RO" for each value in a column on a sheet called `RAW DATA` and put into a cell on a sheet called `ROSS DATA`. Some of the values in that cell have 3 digits after the "RO", and some have 5 digits. To do that I used

```
=REPLACE('RAW DATA'!A3,1,2,"")
```

Then I need to use this new resultant string as the lookup value in a VLOOKUP. The VLOOKUP will be looking at a named range called `DAP` on a sheet called `DAP`, in column 5 for an exact match, and I need it to return that value to the cell.

I have tried using `INDIRECT` in different ways to no avail, and I'm not sure that I fully understand its usage. So at this point I am Googling for a method to do this and at a standstill.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to a) not use caps lock in the title, and b) show an example of what you've tried and what hasn't worked. If you have a specific question, we're happy to help, but right now your question is too broad (e.g. "write my spreadsheet"). Include specific formula and resulting behavior.

Comment: @nhinkle I think this is reasonably clear and really not that broad at all. This is just a case of someone being confused about how to nest functions in a formula, and the solution is pretty straightforward. I'd be happy to post an answer if this is reopened.

Comment: @Excellll reopened. Thanks for editing the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, your `REPLACE` function is in `B3`, you can just use

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,OFFSET(DAP,0,4),1,FALSE)
```

The `OFFSET` function makes the `VLOOKUP` look in the column 4 columns to the right of the first column of `DAP`.

This formula should return your lookup value (i.e., the value of `B3`) if it's found and an error if it is not. From what I can tell, this is what you wanted. If it's not, please leave a comment and let me know what you want.